# Flask route not accessing statement: if request.method == 'POST' provided by ajax object, but works fine on another route

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am struggling to understand why when I have 2 routes why the `if request.method == "POST":` in `@views.route("/", methods =["GET","POST"])` is able to grab the data, but another route: `@views.route("/splits", methods =["GET", "POST"])` does not.

Both route have seperate templates that inherit from index.html, when I submit the form the fisrt route's function returns the data as expected and updates the DOM. When I submit the form from the template rendered from `@views.route("/splits", methods =["GET","POST"])` (splitAnalysis.html) the url redirects to something like: http://127.0.0.1:7000/views/swrsplits?swrNo=12345&fileLable=testing1&folderName=test2, and it doesn't seem like any data is returned.

Edit to add only the most relevent portions of my files

app.py:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from views import views
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/views")
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, port=7000)
```

Views.py:

```
    from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, jsonify, send_from_directory, send_file
    from probe_pull import probe_puller
    from datetime import date
    from pathlib import Path
    import os
    
    
    views = Blueprint(__name__, "views")
    
    @views.route("/", methods =["GET","POST"])
    def trend():
        if request.method == "POST":
            return callProbeExtract(request.form)
        return render_template("Trends.html")
    
    @views.route("/swrsplits", methods =["GET", "POST"])
    def swrPull():
        if request.method == "POST":
            print("hey your in")  
            returnString = f'{request.form["_swrNo"]}__{request.form["_fileLable"]}'
            _outPutFileName = request.form["_folderName"]
            return jsonify({'output':returnString, 'fileName':_outPutFileName})
        return render_template("splitAnalysis.html")
```

index.html - the template the others inherit from (only showing the JQuery):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function primeDOM(firstPass, fileName, filePath, output) {
        if (firstPass) {
          ...Does stuff...
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
        var zipName = {
          fileName: "",
          filePath: "",
        };
        var firstPass = true;
        $("#spinner").hide();
        $("#btn-text-load").hide();

        var currForm = $("#formHolder").children("form").attr("id");
        $(currForm).on("submit", function (e) {
          if ((currForm = "form")) {
            var ajaxData = {
              _mistiList: $("#mistiId").val(),
              _familyName: $("#familyName").val(),
              _logPoint: $("#logPoint").val(),
              _opn: $("#opn").val(),
              _daysBack: $("#daysBack").val(),
              _daysStart: $("#daysStart").val(),
              _folderName: $("#folderName").val(),
            };
            var ajaxUrl = "{{url_for('views.trend')}}";
          } else if ((currForm = "formSWR")) {
            var ajaxData = {
              _swrNo: $("#swrNo").val(),
              _fileLable: $("#fileLable").val(),
              _folderName: $("#folderName").val(),
            };
            var ajaxUrl = "{{url_for('views.swrPull')}}";
          }
          $.ajax({
            data: ajaxData,
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxUrl,
          }).done(function (data) {
            zipName.fileName = data.fileName;
            zipName.filePath = data.output;
            firstPass = primeDOM(
              firstPass,
              zipName.fileName,
              zipName.filePath,
              data.output
            );
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#downloadIcon").click(function () {
          console.log(zipName.fileName);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

trends.html - this is the one that works w/ containers and such removed:

```
    {% extends "index.html" %} {% block content %}
    <form id="form" class="mt-4">
          <textarea
            type="text"
            id="mistiId"
            name="mistiIds"
            placeholder="AE208"
            required
            class="form-control"
            style="height: 93%; width: 100%"
          ></textarea>
          <label for="mistiId">ID List (Seperate with comma):</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="familyName"
                name="familyName"
                placeholder="XXX"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
              <label for="Family (Wildcard with '%')">
               Device Family (Wildcard with '%'):</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="logPoint"
                name="logPoint"
                placeholder="4800"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
              <label for="logPoint">LogPoint:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="opn"
                name="opn"
                placeholder="3600"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
              <label for="opn">Operation:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="daysBack"
                name="daysBack"
                placeholder="200"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
              <label for="daysBack">Days Back:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="daysStart"
                name="daysStart"
                placeholder="195"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
              <label for="daysStart">Start Day:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="folderName"
                name="folderName"
                placeholder="myFolderName"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
              <label for="folderName">Folder Name:</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">
    </button>
    
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

splitAnalysis.html - this is the one that does not appear to return the data (or access the if statement) w/ containers and such removed:

```
      {% extends "index.html" %} {% block content %}
        <form id="formSWR" class="mt-4">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="swrNo"
                    name="swrNo"
                    placeholder="SWR#"
                    required
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                  <label for="swrNo"> SWR Numbers (seperate with comma): 
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="fileLable"
                    name="fileLable"
                    placeholder="fileLable"
                    required
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                  <label for="fileLable">
                    Label For File Names (use "_" instead of space):
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="folderName"
                    name="folderName"
                    placeholder="myFolderName"
                    required
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                  <label for="folderName">Folder Name:</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">
            </button>
        </form>
        {% endblock %}
```

I'm a little bit at a loss as to why one route seems to work fine and the other doesn't. I can see both have the correct string parameters when the respective forms are submitted, and I have added  print("hey your in") to the swrPull() function after the if request.method == "POST" statement and nothing is logged in the console.

```
@views.route("/swrsplits", methods =["GET", "POST"])
def swrPull():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("hey your in")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to follow things.  I suggest you only paste the most relevant parts of your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit embarassing, but the issue was I had a typo in my logical operators:

```
         if ((currForm = "form")) {
            var ajaxData = {
              _mistiList: $("#mistiId").val(),
              _familyName: $("#familyName").val(),
              _logPoint: $("#logPoint").val(),
              _opn: $("#opn").val(),
              _daysBack: $("#daysBack").val(),
              _daysStart: $("#daysStart").val(),
              _folderName: $("#folderName").val(),
            };
            var ajaxUrl = "{{url_for('views.trend')}}";
          } else if ((currForm = "formSWR")) {
            var ajaxData = {
              _swrNo: $("#swrNo").val(),
              _fileLable: $("#fileLable").val(),
              _folderName: $("#folderName").val(),
            };
```

Should be `if ((currForm == "form")) {...` and  `...} else if ((currForm == "formSWR")) {...`

Works as intended now